# First row in datagrid view of VB.Net automatically gets cleared when a row is selected

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagrid

I wanted the default selection of the row on form load should be no row, so that i could create an entry from the text boxes present, but the first row when selected gets automatically cleared off:

[image]

Comment: What's your question?